# Python - audiodiff can't find file that exists

Tags: python, debian, filenotfoundexception, linux-mint, audio-fingerprinting

I'm comparing wav files, this script worked fine until I switched to LMDE Betsy.  The function that is giving me my error is:

```
def already_valid (arg_wav):
    for w in wavs:
         size_arg = getsize(arg_wav.src_path)
         size_w = getsize(w.src_path)
         if 0 < size_w == size_arg and w.src_path != arg_wav.src_path:
             print arg_wav.src_path, "::", w.src_path
             if audiodiff.audio_equal(arg_wav.src_path, w.src_path):
                 return True
    return False
```

My first thought was that it was trying to open the same file twice, but `w.src_path != arg_wav.src_path` should account for that.  I am getting this output:

From my function:

```
/home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/TITAN Recordings/6648/hold1_por.wav :: /home/will/Desktop/soundfiles/TITAN Recordings/6677/hold1_por.wav
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call_diff.py", line 145, in <module>
    verified += handle_wav(p)
  File "call_diff.py", line 73, in handle_wav
    if already_valid(curr_wav):
  File "call_diff.py", line 96, in already_valid
    if audiodiff.audio_equal(arg_wav.src_path, w.src_path):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiodiff/__init__.py", line 51, in audio_equal
    return checksum(name1, ffmpeg_bin) == checksum(name2, ffmpeg_bin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiodiff/__init__.py", line 86, in checksum
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's so odd is that it worked yesterday on Linux Mint 17.1 *and* on Windows 7.  Is this some weird Debian convention I don't know about?  Yes, I double-checked and *both* files exist in the path described.

Comment: There's a chance it's failing to find ffmpeg, rather than your files. Is ffmpeg in your PATH?

Comment: Of course I forgot to install ffmpeg on my new mint!  Thanks, it runs now, is there a way to tell from the traceback that it means it can't find `ffmpeg_bin` rather than one of my files?

Comment: From what's there, not really. I guessed because I saw `ffmpeg_bin`. You could open the audiodiff `__init__.py` and check around line 86 to see what it's actually doing there, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code of audiodiff, you'll see that you need to have *ffmpeg* installed and perhaps to have the path to ffmpeg binary set into FFMPEG_BIN environment variable.

[https://github.com/clee704/audiodiff/blob/master/audiodiff/**init**.py](https://github.com/clee704/audiodiff/blob/master/audiodiff/__init__.py)